# dynamical initialization of std::vector<unique_ptr<class T>>

Tags: c++11, vector, unique-ptr

I have a class Grid declared as follows:

## Grid.h

```
#ifndef DATATEST_GRID_H
#define DATATEST_GRID_H

#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include "Position.h"

class Grid
{
public:
    Grid(int length_x, int length_y);
    ~Grid();

    Position *at(int x, int y);
    void printGrid();

private:
    int length_x, length_y;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Position>> grid;
};

#endif
```

Its most important member variable is the `vector<unique_ptr<Position>>`, which I'm using to simulate a 2-dimensional array whose size is determined at runtime. The class declaration for the Position is as follows:

## Position.h

```
#ifndef DATATEST_POSITION_H
#define DATATEST_POSITION_H

#include <memory>
#include <string>

class Position {
public:
    Position(int x, int y);
    ~Position();

    std::string toString();
    int getX() { return x; };
    int getY() { return y; };

private:
    int x, y;
};

#endif
```

In the Grid's constructor, I want to create the desired number of Positions and add them to the `vector<unique_ptr<Position>>`.

## Grid.cpp

```
#include "Grid.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include "Position.h"

Grid::Grid(int length_x, int length_y) 
    : length_x(length_x), length_y(length_y)
{
    grid.resize(length_x * length_y);   

    for (int x = 0; x < length_x; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < length_y; y++) {
            /* Option 1 */
            std::unique_ptr<Position> temp = std::make_unique<Position>(x, y);
            grid.push_back(std::move(temp));

            /* Option 2 */
            // std::unique_ptr<Position> temp = std::make_unique<Position>(x, y);
            // grid.emplace_back(std::move(temp));

            /* Option 3 */
            // grid.push_back(std::make_unique<Position>(x, y)); 

            /* Option 4 */
            // grid.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Position>(x, y));
        }
    }
}

Grid::~Grid()
{
    grid.clear();
}

Position *Grid::at(int x, int y)
{
    if (x < 0 || x >= length_x || y < 0 || y >= length_y) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    else {
        return grid.at(x * (length_y) + y).get();
    }
}

void Grid::printGrid()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << grid.at(i)->toString() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I'm testing access by calling Position::toString for each `unique_ptr<Position>` and printing the result to the console.

## Position.cpp

```
#include "Position.h"
#include <string>

Position::Position(int x, int y) 
    : x(x), y(y)
{
}

Position::~Position()
{
}

std::string Position::toString()
{
    return "Position(" + std::to_string(x) + ", " + std::to_string(y) + ")";
}
```

And finally, the main function:

## Main.cpp

```
#include "Grid.h"
#include "Position.h"

int main()
{
    Grid g(2, 2);
    g.printGrid();

    return 0;
}
```

No matter which way I populate the `vector<unique_ptr<Position>>`, I always get the following error:

**First-chance exception at 0x0087D8A3 in CombatSim.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
Unhandled exception at 0x0087D8A3 in CombatSim.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.**

As far as I know, I could have one of four problems:
1) I'm adding the unique_ptr to the created Position object to the vector incorrectly
2) I'm using the wrong method to dynamically create Position objects.
3) All of the above.
4) Something I don't know about.

Comment: You're going to have to show us a _program that we can compile_ and run to reproduce the issue. Your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will do fine. The one you've been debugging today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that resizing the grid will first insert `length_x * length_y` unique pointers that all point to `0`. Your `push_back` should be fine but your real elements start at position `length_x * length_y` in the vector. I think removing the line

```
grid.resize(length_x * length_y);
```

should solve the problem. Maybe someone else can explain why this happens.

Comment: Thank you! According to [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/), when resize is called, "If n is greater than the current container size, the content is expanded by inserting at the end as many elements as needed to reach a size of n. If val is specified, the new elements are initialized as copies of val, otherwise, they are value-initialized."

Comment: @user0815 It would be recommended to first reserve space for all those `length_x * length_y` elements before adding them to the vector to avoid repeatedly reallocating the memory.

Comment: Yes, correct. I mistook `resize` and `reserve` as pointed out. Thus the behavior is obvious. I hope it helped anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::vector::reserve(n)` instead of `std::vector::resize(n)` if you are going to `push_back` those *n* elements afterwards.

`resize` will **fill** the vector with initialized objects, so the `vector.size()` will be *n* after that.

`reserve` will just reserve enough space for all *n* element, but will not insert any objects.

Comment: Thank you! It turns out that this solved the problem that I described in the other post.